# How to get all lines between first and last occurrences of specific search string using findstr?

Tags: windows, findstr

My below code prints only the lines matching the search string, but I want all the lines between first and last occurrence of the search string.

```
findstr "110343" suFile.log
```

For example, if my input is as below:

```
Apple
110343
Ball
110343
Cat
Dog
110343
Elephant
```

I want output to be:

```
110343
Ball
110343
Cat
Dog
110343
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? SO is not a "code for me" request platform.

Comment: You can't get this done using just `findstr`: `findstr` can handle text on a line, while you want to process other lines based on that one line. I'd advise you to do some scripting (Perl, Python, Powershell, ...).